# Titanium ACS with WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, titanium

Does anyone know if ACS, a Cloud Storage service by Titanium is compatible with Windows Phone 7? I've been trying to look on the web for details but haven't found anything useful.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears they have a [REST API](http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/rest) and use [OAuth](http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/authentication) for authentication.  It should be no problem to access this API from WP7.  Here is a quick start on [calling REST APIs from WP7](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Accessing_a_REST_Web_Service).  Here's [a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_acsandwindowsphone7_topic2.aspx) that uses OAuth from WP7.

Comment: I'm very new to the whole idea of connecting to a web service. Are there any specific guidelines which you can tell me which I can adhere to?

Comment: The REST API seems very straight forward but I'm having trouble understanding OAuth. Can you please clarify what it is and why I need it? Thank you for your generous help.